# Android xamarin forms: Edit private files

Tags: android, xamarin

I am developing an Android app with Xamarin forms where I have a series of files with different extensions that have been downloaded and stored in my applications private local storage area.
I then have the requirement that users should be able to open these files in the App of their choosing, make any changes and then Save/overwrite that original file. I find however that in quite a lot of Apps, the files open Read-only and in others, the behaviour is inconsistant e.g. in Xodo, PDF files can be edited and saved no problem whilst jpg files always open readonly.

I therefore wonder, is the code correct and if there is any other way to achieve this to maximise the number of Apps able to open files in write mode?
At the point of download, it is not a problem to have the files stored in a different location however this location is stored in a Sqlite database so that the file can be re-uploaded (with changes) at a later date.

I have added the main parts of the code as below:

```
public async Task OpenFileForEditFromPathAsync(string filePath)
        {
            Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(filePath);
            var exists = file.Exists();

            Android.Net.Uri path = Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file);
            string extension = MimeTypeMap.GetFileExtensionFromUrl(Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file).ToString());
            string mimeType = MimeTypeMap.Singleton.GetMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionEdit);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearWhenTaskReset);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantReadUriPermission);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantWriteUriPermission);
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.GrantPersistableUriPermission);


            var uri = FileProvider.GetUriForFile(Android.App.Application.Context, Android.App.Application.Context.PackageName + ".fileprovider", file);

            if (uri != null)
            {
                intent.SetData(uri);
            }

            this.StartActivity(Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Choose App"));
        }

public static class ObjectExtensions
    {
        public static void StartActivity(this object o, Intent intent)
        {
            var context = o as Context;
            if (context != null)
                context.StartActivity(intent);
            else
            {
                intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    }
```

with the manifest settings as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <application android:label="ExampleApp.Android">
      <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
      </provider>
    </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please do NOT post code as links to external resources.  Take the time to post the relevant code inline.

Comment: Sorry Jason, edits made